# Api call returns empty array on album

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-interface, facebook-javascript-sdk

The following url

```
https://graph.facebook.com/10150146071791729
```

returns a valid array, But

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/119357078240091
```

returns error saying "unsupported get request", even though the album is public. please anyone tell me why.. :(

Answer (score 0):

The second one doesn't seem to be a valid album object id. Have a look at this FQL:

```
select aid from album where aid=119357078240091
```

returns

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```